# Pytorch's share_memory_() vs built-in Python's shared_memory: Why in Pytorch we don't need to access the shared memory-block?

Tags: python, pytorch, multiprocessing, shared-memory

Trying to learn about the built-in [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and [Pytorch's `multiprocessing`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/multiprocessing.html) packages, I have observed a different behavior between both. I find this to be strange since [Pytorch's package is fully-compatible](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/multiprocessing.html#:%7E:text=The%20API%20is%20100%25%20compatible%20with%20the%20original%20module) with the built-in package.

Concretely, I'm refering to the way variables are shared between processes. In Pytorch, tensor's are moved to shared_memory via the inplace operation [`share_memory_()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.share_memory_.html#torch.Tensor.share_memory_). On the other hand, we can get the same result with the built-in package by using the [`shared_memory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) module.

The **difference** between both that I'm struggling to understand is that, with the built-in version, we have to explicitely access the shared memory-block inside the launched process. However, we don't need to do that with the Pytorch version.

Here is a **Pytorch**'s toy example showing this:

```py
import time

import torch
# the same behavior happens when importing:
# import multiprocessing as mp
import torch.multiprocessing as mp


def get_time(s):
    return round(time.time() - s, 1)


def foo(a):
    # wait ~1sec to print the value of the tensor.
    time.sleep(1.0)
    with lock:
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------
        # WITHOUT explicitely accessing the shared memory block, we can observe
        # that the tensor has changed:
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------
        print(f"{__name__}\t{get_time(s)}\t\t{a}")


# global variables.
lock = mp.Lock()
s = time.time()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Module\t\tTime\t\tValue")
    print("-"*50)

    # create tensor and assign it to shared memory.
    a = torch.zeros(2).share_memory_()
    print(f"{__name__}\t{get_time(s)}\t\t{a}")

    # start child process.
    p0 = mp.Process(target=foo, args=(a,))
    p0.start()

    # modify the value of the tensor after ~0.5sec.
    time.sleep(0.5)
    with lock:
        a[0] = 1.0

    print(f"{__name__}\t{get_time(s)}\t\t{a}")
    time.sleep(1.5)

    p0.join()
```

which outputs (as expected):

```bash
Module          Time            Value
--------------------------------------------------
__main__        0.0             tensor([0., 0.])
__main__        0.5             tensor([1., 0.])
__mp_main__     1.0             tensor([1., 0.])
```

And here is a toy example with the **built-in** package:

```py
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

import numpy as np


def get_time(s):
    return round(time.time() - s, 1)


def foo(shm_name, shape, type_):
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------
    # WE NEED TO explicitely access the shared memory block to observe
    # that the array has changed:
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------
    existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm_name)
    a = np.ndarray(shape, type_, buffer=existing_shm.buf)

    # wait ~1sec to print the value.
    time.sleep(1.0)
    with lock:
        print(f"{__name__}\t{get_time(s)}\t\t{a}")


# global variables.
lock = mp.Lock()
s = time.time()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Module\t\tTime\t\tValue")
    print("-"*35)

    # create numpy array and shared memory block.
    a = np.zeros(2,)
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=a.nbytes)
    a_shared = np.ndarray(a.shape, a.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    a_shared[:] = a[:]
    print(f"{__name__}\t{get_time(s)}\t\t{a_shared}")

    # start child process.
    p0 = mp.Process(target=foo, args=(shm.name, a.shape, a.dtype))
    p0.start()

    # modify the value of the vaue after ~0.5sec.
    time.sleep(0.5)
    with lock:
        a_shared[0] = 1.0

    print(f"{__name__}\t{get_time(s)}\t\t{a_shared}")
    time.sleep(1.5)

    p0.join()
```

which equivalently outputs, as expected:

```bash
Module          Time            Value
-----------------------------------
__main__        0.0             [0. 0.]
__main__        0.5             [1. 0.]
__mp_main__     1.0             [1. 0.]
```

So what I'm strugging to understand is why we don't need to follow the same steps in both versions, built-in and Pytorch's, i.e. how Pytorch is able to avoid the need to explicitely access the shared memory-block?

P.S. I'm using a Windows OS and Python 3.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pytorch has a simple wrapper around shared memory, python's shared memory module is only a wrapper around the underlying OS dependent functions.

the way it can be done is that you don't serialize the array or the shared memory themselves, and only serialize what's needed to create them by using the `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods [from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#handling-stateful-objects), so that your object acts as both a proxy and a container at the same time.

the following `bar` class can double for a proxy and a container this way, which is useful if the user shouldn't have to worry about the shared memory part.

```py
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
import numpy as np

class bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self._size = 10
        self._type = np.uint8
        self.shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=self._size)
        self._mem_name = self.shm.name
        self.arr = np.ndarray([self._size], self._type, buffer=self.shm.buf)

    def __getstate__(self):
        """Return state values to be pickled."""
        return (self._mem_name, self._size, self._type)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        """Restore state from the unpickled state values."""
        self._mem_name, self._size, self._type = state
        self.shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(self._mem_name)
        self.arr = np.ndarray([self._size], self._type, buffer=self.shm.buf)

def get_time(s):
    return round(time.time() - s, 1)

def foo(shm, lock):
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------
    # without explicitely access the shared memory block we observe
    # that the array has changed:
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------
    a = shm

    # wait ~1sec to print the value.
    time.sleep(1.0)
    with lock:
        print(f"{__name__}\t{get_time(s)}\t\t{a.arr}")

# global variables.
s = time.time()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = mp.Lock()  # to work on windows/mac.

    print("Module\t\tTime\t\tValue")
    print("-" * 35)

    # create numpy array and shared memory block.
    a = bar()
    print(f"{__name__}\t{get_time(s)}\t\t{a.arr}")

    # start child process.
    p0 = mp.Process(target=foo, args=(a, lock))
    p0.start()

    # modify the value of the vaue after ~0.5sec.
    time.sleep(0.5)
    with lock:
        a.arr[0] = 1.0

    print(f"{__name__}\t{get_time(s)}\t\t{a.arr}")
    time.sleep(1.5)

    p0.join()
```

python just makes it much easier to hide such details inside the class without bothering the user with such details.

Edit: i wish they'd make locks non-inheritable so your code can raise an error on the lock, instead you'll find out one day that it doesn't actually lock ... After it crashes your application in production.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). So that's what pytorch does! Playing with your code really helped me to understand it. 
Regarding the lock comment, my bad, as I was using it, it truly does nothing. I've noted that including a lock in the state of the `bar`'s instance, and serializing it, it is correctly shared with the child process.

Answer (score 8):

You are writing a love letter to the pytorch authors.
That is, you are patting them on the back,
congratulating their wrapper efforts as "a job well done!"
It's a lovely library.

Let's take a step back and use a very simple
data structure, a dictionary `d`.
If parent initializes `d` with some values,
and then kicks off a pair of worker children,
each child has a copy of `d`.

How did that happen?
The `multiprocessing` module forked off
the workers, looked at the set of defined
variables which includes `d`, and **serialized**
those (key, value) pairs from parent down to
the children.

So at this point we have 3 independent **copies**
of `d`. If parent or either child modifies `d`,
the other 2 copies are completely unaffected.

Now switch gears to the pytorch wrapper.
You offered some nice concise code that demos
the little .SharedMemory() dance an app would
need to do if we want 3 references to same shared structure
rather than 3 independent copies.
The pytorch wrapper serializes **references**
to common data structure, rather than producing copies.
Under the hood it's doing exactly the dance that you did.
But with no repeated verbiage up at the app level,
as the details have nicely been abstracted away, FTW!

> Why in Pytorch we don't need to access the shared memory-block?

tl;dr: We **do** need to access it. But the library shoulders the burden of worrying about the details, so we don't have to.

Comment: Thank a lot, this comment is not a love letter but your answer really helped me to understand memory sharing better :)